# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::whereBetween() Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5.2

Estou com esse erro na minha consulta, já identifiquei que o uso de `whereBetween` dentro de uma `function` `join` é impossível de utilizar, mas vi que o pessoal conseguiu utilizar o `DB::Raw` e substituir esse `whereBetween`.

A questão é que não encontrei nenhum exemplo de uso do `DB::Raw` dentro de uma `function` `join` e as formas que tentei não tiveram sucesso.

Código:

```
$exec = DB::table('execucao_acompanhamento as a')
        ->join('execucao_acompanhamento_busca_bens as h', function($join)
                                          use($data_busca_1_1, $data_busca_1_2){
            $join->on('a.id','=','h.acompanhamento_id')
                ->where('h.busca_bens_id','=','1')
                ->whereBetween('h.data_busca', ["$data_busca_1_1","$data_busca_1_2"]);
        })
        ->get();
```

Comment: Veja isso: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37298384/1518921

Comment: Então, como eu quero comparar entre um periodo, o whereIn não me ajuda nesse caso, pois o whereIn verifica dentro de um array se naquela tabela existe o valor 1 e 10 por exemplo, mas no meu caso eu tenho que verificar se existe os valores dentro do intervalo de 1 e 10.

Comment: Luiz eu entendo, mas a ideia não é usar aquilo exatamente como esta, mas sim entender como ele usou o raw e adaptou, então você ajustar e adaptar ao seu caso, entende? Eu não sei dizer se vai funcionar pra ti, mas se eu conseguir testar o seu código eu tentarei ver se existe como criar uma alternativa.

Comment: Certo, mas nesse exemplo ele utilizou o raw apenas para um count, até onde eu conheço, não é possível utilizar um between dentro de um raw. Ou isso é possóvel? Tentei de algumas formar aqui e não obtive sucesso.

Answer (score 1):

Tive olhando em outros foruns e encontrei como substituir o whereBetween. Ficou assim.

```
$exec = DB::table('execucao_acompanhamento as a')
->join('execucao_acompanhamento_busca_bens as h', function($join) use($data_busca_1_1, $data_busca_1_2){
    $join->on('a.id','=','h.acompanhamento_id')
        ->where('h.busca_bens_id','=','1')
        ->where('j.data_busca','>=', $data_busca_1_1)
        ->where('j.data_busca','<=', $data_busca_1_2);
})
->get();
```

Comment: Testei com 5.4 e o whereBetween funcionou normal nesse mesmo contexto. Mas como não conheço o comportamento do 5.2 então creio que a sua resposta seja mesma a mais adequada.